# How to find the desktop on any user computer?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I find the desktop or my documents on any user computer

(I don't know the computer name)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) method which will return you the path to the corresponding special folder passed as enum argument. Example:

```
var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do find it easily using [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

Answer (score 3):

The **Environment.SpecialFolder** enumeration has everything you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Environment.SpecialFolder` Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) together with [`Environment.GetFolderPath()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx), for example:

```
var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

This returns the path of the desktop of the currently logged in user. If you want to retrieve the path of the desktop folder for all users, use this instead:

```
var desktopPath = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory);
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that CommonDesktopDirectory is .NET 4 and higher.